# Icomoon icon not displaying correctly

Tags: fonts, icons, jekyll

I'm trying to incorporate icons from a font I exported from Icomoon. I added the CSS from the download directly to my .scss file, and am reference my icon with

```
<i class="icon-checkmark"></i>
```

but all I get in the browser is a square icon with the HTML entity code inside, not the icon itself. I don't get any errors in my console. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you checked the fonts url on sass file?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included your css file in HTML.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```